# Permissions for WSL2 with Docker and web server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, webserver, wsl-2

I'm using WSL2 with an Ubuntu distro.
In the home directory I have a git repository which I access with VSCode via the remote explorer extension. Also the repository has a docker compose file with a webserver, which mounts the code into the /var/www/html directory of that docker container.

Everything works very well, also performance wise.
The only problem I have that I always get some permission issues, either on my side with my WSL2 user that I can't edit files with VSCode which were created by www-data in the docker container or on the other side that the webserver with www-data can't write or created files in the directory.

I tried many commands like:

- sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
- sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/html
- sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
- and more

I used them on both sides, so in WSL2 terminal and in the docker container terminal. But nothing really helps. Any ideas?